# How does Grim Harvest work?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

The Grim Harvest rune for the Threatening Shout reads:

"Enemies are badly shaken and have a 15% chance to drop additional treasure".

What is meant by "treasure" here? Does that mean that the enemy is more likely to drop magic, rare, or legendary loot, or is it just referencing gold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Diablo 3 forums](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CF8QFjAE&url=http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4175550572&ei=4F-2T7HcN4ym8gTG8PXPCg&usg=AFQjCNGlbmXOE0-hEBUidvlZkPEHnG6HmA&sig2=YiY9HCL9894Vd1fFbkA1rg)

it's an additional chance to drop treasure of any kind, gold and/or items.